# bootstrap icons are NOT displaying on the server

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on ASP.NET web application using BOOTSTRAP

while testing n debugging it was working well n good.

But when i published my asp.net web app on the server, its not displaying bootstrap icons.

my code:

```
i class="fa fa-user" / i
```

Can anybody plz suggest me to sort out this issue.

Thanks

Regards,

Comment: share your website url

Comment: Probably you are not serving correctly the icons resoursces; have you got a live site?

Answer (score 0):

I have some exact problem, my resolution is to set **build-action** from **none** to **content** for assets file (ex.font-awesome.css, custom-style.css etc), or just **copy** the file to the server.

To set build-action from none to content, just **right click for the file** desired then select **properties**, look for the build-action then change as you wish.